# How to structure classes in Hibernate for tables with nullable columns?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I have a table that has values that can be null in it, I'd initially coded up my class with primitives ints for those values, however I get the following exception when one of them contains null:
Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter

However when I try to change the setters to the java.lang equivalent I get a no such method error on the setter.

How do you structure the class if you know the values may be null?

I've tried:

- Primitive setter/getter primitive private variable.
- Primitive setter/getter object variable
- Object setter/setter getter object private variable

All to no avail.

I'm connecting to a MySQL DB on a customer site, to test this, I tested against a SQL Server DB and didn't get this issue but I don't think any of the variables were set to null on that machine.

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0 and Hibernate 3 (I developed for hibernate 4 and JBoss 7.1 but had to downgrade because for some reason the customer's IT policy wont let them use anything later than JBoss 5.1.0)

**Edit:** Turns out the NoSuchMethodException was a JSP issue not a hibernate issue, clearing JBoss' temp dir and redeploying the application resolved it.

I'm accepting the correct answer to the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use object wrappers for both variables and getters/setters and it handles null correctly for me. If your DB columns allow nulls, I recommend using object wrappers all the way.

Comment: I'll retry but when I did use object wrappers I got MethodDoesNotExist Exceptions on the getter method.

Comment: Turns out the exception was a JSP issue not Hibernate.